# How to trigger or Run a method inside running exe file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api

I have a list of the client on the web app at the same time there is an executable program running each client machine.I want to add a button to my web application and when the button has clicked a method inside an executable program must run and program call the user phone number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communication between Chrome javascript and native Windows code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214431/communication-between-chrome-javascript-and-native-windows-code)

Comment: What's the desktop app? Can you link it with the site via a `tel:` style hyperlink? Would it respond to that, if mapped by the user's machine. Some software e.g. Skype will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) for this.

SignalR give you

> the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens

The same way someone create a chat desktop app, you could create a app that wait for a message in a site, then trigger an execution of your executable program.

Example how to create a Desktop Application

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have research about SignalR it seems to help me.I have two console app which talks each other one of them works as a server and another one like client .i want to implement client-side app as rest API using ASP.Net MVC but I can't find any resources about it.I want an HTML link and a message on it like a query string, on the server side I want to read that query string and make something I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your web app can add a value in the registry.
On your windows app you set a function in a timer that checks for that value and triggers the desired action.

My bad about the registry as web app will not have access to it. Use cookies instead.

Comment: How to write a key to a register? Does the client machine let me write to its register?

Comment: store and retrieve a value from cookies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599287/create-read-and-erase-cookies-with-jquery     and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674244/cookies-and-desktop-application